# How can we serialize or deserialize the object of a class in c++.Is there any predefined library?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any predefined library to serialize the object in c++.
If there is not how can we do that.

Comment: This question is OT for this site, IMHO. Having said that, check [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: I *think*, by "predefined library", the OP means "part of the STL".  In which case the question is on-topic.

Comment: @MartinBonner You might be right.

Comment: I would recommend writing your own serialization thing above some textual protocol à la [JSON](http://json.org/). Notice that C++11 does not have any reflection mechanism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no serialization library defined as part of the C++ standard.  You will have to use a third party library (and requests for recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow), or you will have to write your own (and "how should I write a serialization library?" is probably "too broad").